# Gauge invariant and Lorentz invariant in Weinberg's QFT textbook (eq. 8.1.5)

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, gauge-theory, lorentz-symmetry, noethers-theorem, gauge-invariance

In Weinberg's QFT textbook, using a gauge transformation $$A_{\mu}(x) \rightarrow A_{\mu}(x) + \partial_{\mu}\epsilon(x)\tag{8.1.3},$$ it has:
$$\delta I_{M} = \int d^4 x \frac{\delta I_{M}}{\delta A_{\mu}}\partial_{\mu}\epsilon(x), \tag{8.1.4}$$
where $I_{M}$ is the part of the action for matter.
And Weinberg says that, from Lorentz invariance of $I_{M}$, it has:
$$\partial_{\mu}\frac{\delta I_{M}}{\delta A_{\mu}} = 0.\tag{8.1.5}$$
I don't see how it can be derived from Lorentz invariant.

Comment: I don't know if I would say lorentz invaraince.. i would first say it was from noether's theorem

Comment: perhaps he meant to say gauge invariance.. but im not sure

Comment: It looks like current conservation.

Comment: Under a Lorentz transformation the $A_\mu$ transforms as a 4-vector up to the gauge transformation, hence the action is Lorentz invariant only if the condition Weinberg writes (which is nothing but current consevartion) holds true.